# How to refere to .po/.pot files in website code?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, po

I want to translate my page with po files. Unfortunately I don't know how should I refere to .po file in the code. 
Website have been written in php/html with wordpress commands.

Answer (score 0):

There are loads of libraries available on Packagist that can handle gettext translations in `.po` files. Here's just one of them:

https://packagist.org/packages/gettext/gettext

Just require in with composer. Of course, there may be wordpress plugins using these libs, which might be simpler to set up.

Here's i18n docs for wordpress, which mentions usage with .po files

https://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers#PO_files